# Docker CLI command to print an image's configuration JSON object?

Tags: docker

For the life of me I can't figure out how to get the Docker CLI to print the configuration object of an image - the object that gets hashed to create the image ID.

`docker inspect` doesn't print this.

The only way I know of to get this is `docker save <image> -o <image>.tar`, untar the image, and get the `<image id>.json` file from the top-level. This is pretty clunky and inefficient though.

Comment: The content of this file is pretty much the same as `docker inspect`, except for a few that can be obtained with other Docker commands - but in a different format. What information are you missing ?

Comment: I wanted to programmatically determine if a given image is different from another in terms of the actual contents of the filesystem. I realized that both docker inspect and the configuration object provide the layer digests, which I can use for this purpose.

docker inspect <image> --format '{{join .RootFS.Layers " "}}' | sha256sum | cut -f1 -d' '

The intent of this is to use it as a cache key for a build process.

Comment: The reason the image ID itself isn't suitable for this is because it is computed from the entire config object, which includes timestamps of when each step in the build was run / layer was created, which is not relevant to the image contents itself having changed.